# improving the creation of a table in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, ddl, create-table

I need help to improve a table creation in teradata.
this table has a huge data and we retrieve the data from it heavily

Comment: Your question is not clear.explain more

Comment: This seems to be not enough information to help you.

Comment: Define a good Primary Index and partition the table properly

Comment: Please show your current table definition and how you expect to access the data from the table (i.e. what columns you use on searches and joins that reference your table).

Comment: Cluster the table on the best key(s) combination, keep stats current, esp. after the batch loads.

Answer (score 0):

To improve data retrieval you may use the below:
1. partition the table(range,case,date).
2. use compress in columns, so that values occurring again and again will be stored as part of table headers.
3. choose indexes(UPI/PI) wisely.